# Carregar arquivo javascript junto com infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax

Preciso recarregar uma função JS assim que rolar a página com `infinite scroll`, em AJAX.

Quando a página é rolada o arquivo JS precisa acompanhar.

Comment: Sergio,
Desculpa pela complicação. 
"Assim que rolar a página" me refiro ao scroll.
Estou trabalhando com infinite scroll e gostaria que minha função fosse aplicada também nos próximos.

Segue um exemplo http://shopluxo.com.br/maquiagem

Comment: Estou utilizando uma função em uma classe e precisaria que ela se repetisse no infinite scroll, não sei se consegui me expressar com clareza.

Comment: Sergio, 
Consegui resolver, problema muito simples e estava quebrando a cabeça rs. Agradeço a disposição em ajudar. Abraços

Comment: Lucas, óptimo. Eu vou apagar os comentários aqui. Na próxima vez coloque mais informação. Há muita gente a querer ajudar, mas sem saber tudo ninguém arrisca dar palpites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela lógica:

- Quando rolar a página -> executa `funcao()`;
- quando executar `funcao()` -> faz o que você deseja.

Tenta imaginar que o engatilhador é parecido com um `hover` ou `click`, mas seria, dessa vez, no `scroll`. Mais especificamente: *quando o scroll atingir o extremo baixo da viewport, execute algo (e é aqui que entra o AJAX).*

Qual a dificuldade nessa lógica?

Para fins técnicos, a sua questão está bem vaga.

Comment: Desculpa pela falta de clareza,
Criei uma função em uma classe e gostaria que se repetisse no infinite scroll também, porque quando o infinite é carregado não trás a função. 
Vou reproduzir a sua lógica. Obrigado!

Comment: Disponha! Qualquer coisa estamos à disposição. =)